# Remove function for a specific element │$(this).off() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a click event to `.call` elements like that

```
$('body div').on('click', '.call', function() {
  $(this).off('click'); //after click i want to unbind the 'click' for this .call only
                        //however its not workinng.

  *... some code here ....*
})
```

If i do `$(body div).off('click', '.call')`, all `.call` elements lost their functionality. I dont want that. How i can remove `click` function from just clicked `.call`

Comment: because the event is not attached to the element you are removing it from. So you would need to add different logic. Can you remove the class call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not unbind the click from the element since the event is not attached to that element. So you need to handle it by either removing the class that you are looking for in the event delegation or add logic of some sort to see if it is clicked.

If you can remove the class, that would be the easiest solution.

```
$('body div').on('click', '.call', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("call");
  /* rest of logic */
})
```

or you can add a class and check for it

```
$('body div').on('click', '.call', function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  if (elem.hasClass("called")) return;
  elem.addClass("called");
  /* rest of logic */
})
```

you could use data() instead of a class or you could add :not logic to the event delegation selector.

Comment: i am gonna mark this answer as true answer since there is no way to remove function, and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using `$().one` http://api.jquery.com/one/

This binds a callback to an element once, and unbinds it once it has been executed.